# How can I use PHP array or json response in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

let me show you my flow briefly.

when I am calling an Ajax from the index.phtml file the ajax returns me this response.

```
Array
(
    [Data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [PlayerId] => 201503261611120312176355026
                    [PlayerName] => Leonel Messi
                    [PlayerPossition] => Striker
                    [PlayerPrice] => 15
                    [PlayerNationality] => Argentina
                    [ImageUrl] => messi.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [PlayerId] => 2015040711252904291525683176
                    [PlayerName] => Simon Mignolet
                    [PlayerPossition] => Goalkeeper
                    [PlayerPrice] => 12
                    [PlayerNationality] => Belgium
                    [ImageUrl] => Mignolet.jpg
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [PlayerId] => 201503301517200320707502096
                    [PlayerName] => Petr Cech
                    [PlayerPossition] => Goalkeeper
                    [PlayerPrice] => 10
                    [PlayerNationality] => czech Republic
                    [ImageUrl] => Petr.jpg
                )
)
```

This is because of When I am calling an API it is giving me the json string like this and I am decoding it so we will get the above out put.

```
{"Data":[{"PlayerId":"201503261611120312176355026","PlayerName":"Leonel Messi","PlayerPossition":"Striker","PlayerPrice":"15","PlayerNationality":"Argentina","ImageUrl":"messi.jpg"},
         {"PlayerId":"2015040711252904291525683176","PlayerName":"Simon Mignolet","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"Belgium","ImageUrl":"Mignolet.jpg"},
         {"PlayerId":"201503301517200320707502096","PlayerName":"Petr Cech","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"czech Republic","ImageUrl":"Petr.jpg"}]
}
```

Finally what is my questions are.

> 1. I want to use the response of API in javascript as array so,I am doing json_decode on the string coming from the api,I should decode the string or ket as it is as a json String  for further use in javascript?if yes then how can I use the json string in javascript as array?
> 2. if no then how can I use the PHP array that I have shown above in javascript as array.?

Help is needed!
It just need the guidance that how to use it, i have seen manny question on this topic but not getting it properly.

This is the full response..

```
{"Data":[{"PlayerId":"201503261611120312176355026","PlayerName":"Leonel Messi","PlayerPossition":"Striker","PlayerPrice":"15","PlayerNationality":"Argentina","ImageUrl":"messi.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711252904291525683176","PlayerName":"Simon Mignolet","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"Belgium","ImageUrl":"Mignolet.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201503301517200320707502096","PlayerName":"Petr Cech","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"czech Republic","ImageUrl":"Petr.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711263304331239304618","PlayerName":"Mario Balotelli","PlayerPossition":"Forward","PlayerPrice":"13","PlayerNationality":"Italy","ImageUrl":"Mario.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711153004301142178636","PlayerName":"John Terry","PlayerPossition":"Defender","PlayerPrice":"15","PlayerNationality":"England","ImageUrl":"Terry.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015033015173503352044674486","PlayerName":"Wayne Rooney","PlayerPossition":"Striker","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"England","ImageUrl":"Rooney.jpeg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711274604461644280531","PlayerName":"Glen Johnson","PlayerPossition":"Defender","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"England","ImageUrl":"Johnson.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201504071121180418898562745","PlayerName":"Wojciech Szczesny","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"Poland","ImageUrl":"Szczesny.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201504071121500450766284368","PlayerName":"Theo Walcott","PlayerPossition":"Forward","PlayerPrice":"13","PlayerNationality":"England","ImageUrl":"Walcott.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"0","PlayerName":"Petr Cech","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"czech Republic","ImageUrl":"Petr.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201504101708340434430387485","PlayerName":"Petr Cech","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"czech Republic","ImageUrl":"Petr.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015032616092803281211739999","PlayerName":"Leonel Messi","PlayerPossition":"Striker","PlayerPrice":"15","PlayerNationality":"Argentina","ImageUrl":"messi.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711193204321670945005","PlayerName":"onny Evans","PlayerPossition":"Defender","PlayerPrice":"11","PlayerNationality":"England","ImageUrl":"Evans.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201503311244410341392250417","PlayerName":"Diego Costa","PlayerPossition":"Striker","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"Span","ImageUrl":"diego.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711181504151664744966","PlayerName":"Wayne Rooney","PlayerPossition":"Forward","PlayerPrice":"15","PlayerNationality":"England","ImageUrl":"Rooney.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201504071117260426381135053","PlayerName":"David de Gea","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"Spain","ImageUrl":"David.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711224104411470384753","PlayerName":"Tomas Rosicky","PlayerPossition":"Midfielder","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"czech Republic","ImageUrl":"Rosicky.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711270704071555972375","PlayerName":"Steven Gerrard","PlayerPossition":"Midfielder","PlayerPrice":"15","PlayerNationality":"England","ImageUrl":"Gerrard.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015033112335503551596743050","PlayerName":"Diego Costa","PlayerPossition":"Striker","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"Brazil","ImageUrl":"diego.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711145204521635036421","PlayerName":"John Obi Mikel","PlayerPossition":"Midfielder","PlayerPrice":"11","PlayerNationality":"Nigeria","ImageUrl":"John.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711141204121342616372","PlayerName":"Didier Drogba","PlayerPossition":"Forward","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"C\u00f4te d\u2019Ivoire","ImageUrl":"Didier.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201504071118430443104059381","PlayerName":"Michael Carrick","PlayerPossition":"Midfielder","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"England","ImageUrl":"Carrick.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201504091258150415433179519","PlayerName":"Petr Cech1","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"czech Republic","ImageUrl":"Petr.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201504071123160416447868423","PlayerName":"Laurent Koscielny","PlayerPossition":"Defender","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"France","ImageUrl":"Koscielny.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"20150407111123042372799765","PlayerName":"Petr Cech","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"czech Republic","ImageUrl":"Petr.jpg"}],"requestId":"1"}
```

This is the errorImage..

[image]

My js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/home/getPlayers',
                            success: function (data) {
                                showPlayers(data);
                            }

                        });

                        function showPlayers(data) {

                            console.log(data);
                            data = JSON.parse(data);

                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: if you want that JSON string used by your javascript, then you don't really need to decode it at all

Comment: so how can i use that json string as an array I have tried with data.Data,data['Data'] where datais var and 'Data is the first key'.but its not working

Comment: Have a look on Article: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/
it take json string and parse it into array than you can run a look on that array values.

Comment: @Daedalus means Data is a key  and it has array

Comment: after doing `JSON.parse(json);` I am doing `data.Data[0]`it is giving me the object but the problem is an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u` what can be reason behind that?

Comment: @BhavikJoshi Check the network tab and the request to view the response.

Comment: in network tab I am having only images of site

Comment: @BhavikJoshi Make sure your console is open when you do the ajax request; the request **will** appear in the network tab.  Click it, go to response, and report back.

Comment: @BhavikJoshi Firstly, an image is no help; secondly, that's not what I requested.  1) Network tab; find the ajax request 2) Click that request 3) click response tab.  I'm _betting_ there is more to the response you're getting back than just the json; rather, I'm expecting to see an error message, and not the one you posted.

Comment: sry but There is only json string

Comment: yeah but it is on 3 line so is there any blank space there?

Comment: @BhavikJoshi Are you making an ajax request?  Let's be clear about things.

Comment: @BhavikJoshi Then post the response to the ajax request.  I'll make a picture for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77483/discussion-between-bhavik-joshi-and-daedalus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get your JavaScript variable with

```
var obj = {"Data":[{"PlayerId":"201503261611120312176355026","PlayerName":"Leonel Messi","PlayerPossition":"Striker","PlayerPrice":"15","PlayerNationality":"Argentina","ImageUrl":"messi.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"2015040711252904291525683176","PlayerName":"Simon Mignolet","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"12","PlayerNationality":"Belgium","ImageUrl":"Mignolet.jpg"},{"PlayerId":"201503301517200320707502096","PlayerName":"Petr Cech","PlayerPossition":"Goalkeeper","PlayerPrice":"10","PlayerNationality":"czech Republic","ImageUrl":"Petr.jpg"}]}
```

Now you can access the elements like this for example:

```
obj.Data[0].PlayerId
```

To parse or create JSON strings, there are these two functions:

```
JSON.parse()
JSON.strigify()
```

Comment: actually what I have done I have called an Ajax and in its success function I have called an another function showData() and I have passed the response of the success function to the showData() in that function I showing the data.Data[0];its not working undefined 0 error but when I am doing JSON.parase() and printing data.Data its giving me the object but the error is also there `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

Comment: @BhavikJoshi We can't see your screen, and unless you read back to us what I told you to look for, we can't help you further.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON.parse(json);` to convert it into object, the use that object! :)

Here's a demo to show you what it returns: http://jsfiddle.net/Lekmnxzb/

Comment: I have done this but I facing this errors `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

Comment: I do a test, you can take a look at this  giving-link above! (in your developper tools)

Comment: no json outputing correctly there is no error for that

Comment: yeah, there is an error in your output json. I just add `]` before the last of the closing brace `}`

Comment: So you should to check the code that generate your json file!

Comment: I am just giving teh full response of the json you can check it

Comment: @BhavikJoshi Won't matter if there's more than json there, and I'm betting there is.